# Use Results of Stored Procedure in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Stored Procedure(SP) in MS SQL 2008 R2 I'm building that requires a list of users to narrow down the data returned.

The system I'm working on has a GetUsers SP which returns a list of users, and I need to then use this to limit the results returned from the SP I am working on myself.

I've had a look at TABLE variables, but not sure if this is quite what I need.

How would I go about integrating the results of one SP into the where clause of another SP?

Comment: You can achieve this with Stored procedure output parameters. Here is a link to an msdn article on how to : [Stored proc output parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take the results of your SP by

```
DECLARE @yourtablevariable TABLE (fields....)    

INSERT INTO @yourtablevariable
EXEC GetUsers
```

Then

```
SELECT *
FROM othertable
    INNER JOIN @yourtablevariable users on othertable.userid=users.userid
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM othertable
WHERE userid in (SELECT UserID FROM @yourtablevariable)
```

Alternatively, if possible, you could convert GetUsers to a table valued function.

Comment: That is where I have gotten so far.

Comment: I also would preferring a table valued function instead of a stored procedure.

Comment: When I declare the table variable, do I need to specify all of the fields the SP outputs, or just the ones I need?

Comment: I really wonder why MSFT writes things like sp_estimate_data_compression_savings as stored procedure and not as table valued function :(

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server if the SP returns a `TABLE`, than the best way to use a *table variable* **(@Table)** or *memory table* **(#Table)** if the returned amount of data is bigger.